# Changing formula in different cells in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheet I am trying edit a formula in multiple cells. Here is the formula I am working with,

`=importrange ("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19iPtirjfk4MUwPV60zLbkVKvh96GE5z8g7B0sOgCZ_w/edit?usp=sharing", "Postsecondary!g7")`

and  I am trying to edit the hyper link in the formula and apply to multiple cell but I don't to make sure that the cell won't lose its position and sequence order.

I try figuring it out on my own, but no clue how to do it. copying and pasting is slow and I want to know a faster way to do it.

Comment: CTRL+H (Search and replace)  ??

Comment: try that but I am not sure if I am doing it right. within the formula I am just trying to replace the hyperlink and hopefully not change the order of where the cells is being place.

Comment: Please make a backup of your google-sheet, try the replace, and (when all is working) draw the conclusion that you learned something. 